# How to override has_perm() and get_all_permission() method in Django

Tags: django

I am confused to customization of permission. I want to create a custom user model,so I try to override has_perm and get_all_permission method. How can I check wether a user gains a permission in has_perm()? I find that get_all_permission() only return a set. If the permission is in the set that get_all_permission return,it means that user has the permission? Also,the permission need add into the user part of permission table if a permission is assigned to a user?

Here is code:

```
# declare a set to hold permission that need add to user
perm_list = set()
  def get_user_type(self):
    return "Staff"
  # if permission is in the permission set, return true otherwise return false
  def has_perm(self, perm, obj=None):
    if perm in self.get_all_permissions():
      return True
    return False
  # return all the user permission
  def get_all_permissions(self, obj=None):
        return self.perm_list
  # assign permission to the user 
  def assign_perm(self,perm,object=None):
    self.perm_list.add(perm)
```

Comment: Hello, can you give us more details about to what you are trying to achieve? Is there anything you are trying to do that isn't covered by `PermissionsMixin`[https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/auth/customizing/#custom-users-and-permissions]?

Comment: Thank you for narrowing down the range. PermissionsMixin is what I am looking for. When my custom user model inherits PermissionsMixin class, I need include all methods of PermissionsMixin in my custom model and fill detail in the method? Or, I can call the method with parameters directly?

Comment: You only need to add the methods to your class declaration if you need to change their behaviour.